# limiting the text box to have only particular limit of numbers and characters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box with label name Employee Id and a text box  to provide employee id now to this text box i should set a validation to have a limit up to 5 numbers or characters if the user tries to enter more than 5 characters or numbers it should display an error message your maximum limit is only 5.

Employee ID*

here i have no button to the text box hence while entering only if the limit exceeds 5 it should display the error message before going to next text box.can you please help me out.

Comment: Is this web forms or mvc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below code will help you.
Maximum and Minimum character length validation for 5 character.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "TextBox1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression = "^[\s\S]{0,5}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Your maximum limit is only 5"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "TextBox1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression = "^[\s\S]{5,}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Minimum required limit is 5"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET you will have validation controls, for this case you can use Regular Expression controller

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "TextBox1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression = "^[\s\S]{0,5}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Maximum 5 characters allowed."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

If you are using HTML5 you can set a pattern also like below that also will show validation

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" pattern=".{5,5}" class="text-center" autocomplete="off" id="yearofManufacture" required  placeholder="Year of Manufacture">
```

In the second approach you don't need to add any plugins also

Answer (score 2):

try this it will work

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate ="TextBox2" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression = "^[\s\S]{0,5}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Maximum 5 characters allowed."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules#.22add.22rules):

```
$("#myinput").rules( "add", {
  required: true,
  maxlength: 5,
  messages: {
    required: "Required input",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, at most {0} characters are allowed")
  }
});
```

You can include it in your project via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.validation) or **Visual Studio Nuget Manger**

Follow this **step by step Tutorial**: [JQuery Validation Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/jquery-validation-with-Asp-Net-web-form/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `textBox.MaxLength=5;` so the user can't actually write more than 5 characters, why would you need an error message? This should be enough.